# f is surjective ⇐⇒ $∀V ⊂ Y$, $f(f^−1 (V ))$ = V prove?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions

$f$ is surjective ⇐⇒ $∀V ⊂ Y$, $f(f^{−1} (V ))$ = $V$ 
This is an assertion and i said it was true. But i am confused as to what is referred to as the domain and range in this question. I would say that $X -> V$ and that $y ∈ V$ . As $f$ is surjective, there exists an $x ∈ X$ such that $f(x) = y$. So $x ∈ f^{−1}(V)$ and 
$y = f(x)$ ∈ $f(f^{−1}(V))$. But what is capital $Y$ in this case? like is it $X$ mapping onto $Y$ or mapping onto $V$. And is $V$ a group of values in the range $(Y)$?  And also, in the solutions they wrote that as $y ∈ V$ is arbitrary, we have $f(f^{−1}(V)) ⊃ V$. I don't understand the $⊃$ symbol or what is meant by y being arbitrary. Can someone explain all my doubts please XD

Comment: Do you want the proof as well?

Answer (score 0):

**First question:** $Y$ is the codomain of $f: X \rightarrow Y$. In this case you are taking any subset $V \subset Y$.

**Second question:** Not necessarily, it will be a subset of the range if $f$ is surjective.

**Third question:** We say that $A \subset  B$ when $\forall a\in A \Rightarrow a \in B$. So taking an arbitrary $y \in V$ and showing that $y \in f(f^{-1}(V))$ means that $V \subset f(f^{-1}(V))$. The symbol $\supset$, for example in $B \supset A$ is just another way of saying $A \subset B$.